# JSON Parse in C#

Tags: c#, json

What is wrong with this code?

**JSON**

```
cities: [
{
    city: {
        id: 1,
        name: "A.S.Peta",
        status: "Active"
    }
},..............
```

**C# Code**

```
public class Cities
{
    public City[] cities;    
}

public class City
{
    public int id; //{ get; set; }
    public string name; //{ get; set; }
    public string status; //{ get; set; }
}

//De-Serialization
var jsSerialize = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var cities = jsSerialize.Deserialize<Cities>(result);
```

Not populating internal object City. but showing collection with all records. Any Idea?

Comment: You can do one thing. Before preparing JSON object. You can check for a dummy JSON by serializing it on the server side and keeping a debugger.

Comment: before Deserialize, did you try to serialize and see if the JSON string you are using is same as it generate, I think there is extra { } going in ... not sure though

Comment: Simply try var jsSerialize = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var cities = jsSerialize.Serialize(new Cities()); and keep Debugger on the next statement

Comment: Note there is a case difference between `city, cities` and `City, Cities`.

Answer (score 8):

The "inner" `city` in your json object is adding a nested object within the array.

Try this json code :

```
{
    "cities": [
    {  
        "id": 1,
        "name": "A.S.Peta",
        "status": "Active"
    },
    {  
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Strasbourg",
        "status": "Active"
    }
    ]
}
```

If you need to stick to your originial json structure, you can try this c# code:

```
public class City2
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public City2 city { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<City> cities { get; set; }
}
```

This code has been automatically generated by this very useful web tool: [json2C#](http://json2csharp.com/#)

Comment: _Invalid JSON primitive: cities._

Comment: @RoyiNamir: you shoud wrap the whole jscon into a pair of brackets. I update my code to reflect this.

Comment: HOwever please notice that `{  
        id: 1,
        name: "A.S.Peta",
        status: "Active"
    }` is not a valid json. it's just that the JSS tolerate it.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Why is that JSON object invalid?

Comment: @stakx try it yourself http://jsonlint.com/. each object key should come under `"`. http://i.stack.imgur.com/lzhFy.jpg

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I follow your advise in my answer. Didn't know jslint before. Thanks for that*

Comment: @Steve Thank you so much for your help and great observation :)